# How can I remove a specific element from my array generated by a blaze helper?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, meteor-blaze

I have a helper class that pushes an element into an array when a checkbox is checked and should remove the element when it is unchecked. I am able to successfully push the element to the array but having trouble removing it.

I am noticing some curious behavior. For instance, unchecking the element also pushes it to the array making a duplicated of it instead of removing it from the array. If I console log the index value, I get -1 for each array element that I'm trying to remove.

Here is the Blaze Code:

```
Template.Job_setup_page.onCreated(function homePageOnCreated() {

    this.checkedJobs = [];

});

Template.Job_setup_page.events({
    'click .filled-in'(event, instance) {
        var currentId = event.target.id;

        if($(".filled-in").is(':checked')){
            instance.checkedJobs.push({
                instruction: currentId,
                quantity: 1
            })
        }
        else {
            var index = instance.checkedJobs.indexOf(currentId);
            instance.checkedJobs.splice(index, 1);
            console.log("This is the current Id", currentId);
            console.log("this is the index", index);
        };
    },
});
```

Comment: This: `instance.checkedJobs.indexOf(currentId)` will always return `-1` because your array contains objects: `{instruction: number, quantity: number}` not numbers. You'll have to loop through the array to find the object that has a specific `instruction` value.

Comment: Why don't you take a different approach and forget about removing the element from the array? Create a function that is triggered with onchange that makes a new array of all the checked fields. Each time a checkbox is checked or unchecked the array is created (empty) and adds all the checked fields. That will save you a lot of code writing.

Comment: @Kobbe Each of the elements also has a dropdown with a quantity in it. How would I tell the onChange function to add that value to the object as well?

Comment: I don't know the details of your form or whatever it is that is checked and whatever the dropdown is with whatever options. Without knowing the details, it boils down to adding these values to an array when a checkbox is checked. Why not re-add all the values of all the checkboxes and dropdown options, the same way you added them individually when checked, by looping through all the fields? I am not presenting a solution to your approach but a different approach.

Comment: @Titus Could you provide an example on how I can loop through the array? I'm a bit confused on the syntax for searching for a specific part of the object.

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` searches for an element itself and will not be able to match an object by its `instruction` property. You should instead use a for-loop to iterate over your `checkedJobs` array and compare each `instruction` to `currentId` in order to find the correct index. Replace the contents of your `else` block with the following:

```
var jobs = instance.checkedJobs
for (var i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
  if (jobs[i].instruction === currentId) {
    instance.checkedJobs.splice(i, 1)
    console.log('currentId:', currentId)
    console.log('index:', i)
  }
}
```

Comment: You fixed the -1 index problem thank you! I'm still getting the issue where its pushing to the array instead of being removed. I don't think it has anything to do with your solution. I'll keep looking and see what's going on with my code. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: @RP12 Try using `$(this).is(':checked')` instead of `$(".filled-in").is(':checked')`. Currently, you're checking if any of the checkboxes with class `filled-in` is checked instead of checking just the one that was clicked.